# What health risks are associated with expired condoms?

Tags: contraception

Condoms have an expiry date, usually about five years from their production date, as far as I can tell.

Obviously, it means their effectiveness is dramatically reduced if used after that expiry time (and chance for tearing/holes increase), so there would be the usual risk of having unprotected sex if used for that purpose.

Are there any other health risks beyond that? If there are, would they occur by simply handling the condom or using it for something other than its intended purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: using expired condom might lead to irritation on the skin of the sex organs involved in the act, and might also lead to skin inflammation and rash.

---

After some self research, I found [this article](https://www.selfgrowth.com/articles/complications-associated-with-using-expired-condoms) which while not scientific and official, is written by someone who appears to know what they're talking about.

Quoting the relevant part: (part about pregnancy isn't relevant to my case since the question is purely about health)

> Here are some of the common risks linked with using expired condoms:
>
> ...
>
> - Irritation: As mentioned earlier, a condom which has crossed its expiration date may get dried and weak. A dried and weak condom can cause irritation on the skin of your sex organ and also in the vagina. It can also lead to skin inflammation and rash.